# Assessing Wardrobe's Protection from Sunlight

Tags: lighting, windows, furniture

I'm in an urban environment and my apartment doesn't leave me with many choices with some of my larger furniture items. Namely, my wardrobe ended up having to be placed in the extended indoor balcony. This area faces south and has sliding windows on all 3 walls, comparable to a large bay window. I placed my wardrobe so that it faced west, which you will see in the floor plan only has partial exposure to a window (just 1 window).

[image]

**Question:** If there is legitimate cause for concern for color-fading/distortion on my clothes inside the wardrobe from prolonged sunlight (either from the front doors, or the back of the wardrobe that faces the east), what are some possible solutions?

**Further Clarification:**

- Wardrobe Door Type - double outward swinging doors
- Wardrobe Door Material - particle board
- Wardrobe Door Color - black
- Wardrobe Door Thickness - 1 in
- Wardrobe Back Material - not sure, looks like really thin wood
- Wardrobe Back Thickness - 3mm
- Wardrobe Back Color - cardboard brown

**Note:** There are curtains all the way around, but I'm not sure how much they will help in terms of preventing sunlight from hitting my wardrobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your clothes won't fade from sunlight.  They may take heat damage, but only if the cloth is very high end, e.g., silks, etc. and if the area has no A/C.

As for the wardrobe itself, it will take some damage, but if you keep the drapes closed (and if those directly next to it are reasonably opaque), then it will take years for fading to occur.